# Power Query - replacing text in a new column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am new to Power Query in Excel and my question is:

I have a text column with date in this format "09-Feb-17 A".  To remove the text " A" and populate the date info in a new column (custom column?), I have used this code:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Start Date", each Replacer.ReplaceText([Start], " A",""))
```

**Problem is** some of the dates are in correct format i.e. without " A".  For those dates I get an error:

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value #date(2019, 1, 11) to
>   type Text. Details:
>       Value=11/01/2019
>       Type=Type

Is there any way to solve this issue within power query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try` `otherwise` to deal with both data types:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Start Date", each try Date.FromText(Replacer.ReplaceText([Start], " A","")) otherwise DateTime.Date([Start]), type date)
```

Or this, which will extract the date before the first space, irrespective of which (or how many) characters follow:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Start Date", each try Date.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Start], " ")) otherwise DateTime.Date([Start]), type date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

- Change the column Data type to `Text` (dates --> date time)
- Extract the portion of the string prior to the `space`
- *Optional* Change column Data type to `Date`

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dates", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Dates]," ")),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Dates"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks Ron but couldn't get it to work - obviously due to my limited knowledge.